# Strange undefined symbol behaviour in shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, undefined-symbol

I have encountered a strange case of undefined symbols in a share library that I cannot resolve. Let's say that my program needs to use a library `A`, which in turn depends on another library `B`, neither of which I can modify.

I first build library `B` using their own automake system, which creates both static `libB.a` and `libB.so` libraries. The static library `libB.a` contains some duplicated mangled symbols, originating from different object files, some of which are undefined. This seems normal to me. The shared library `libB.so` contains only one version of each of these symbols, none of which are undefined.

Then I build library `A` using, again, their own build system (not automake this time but some poorly written makefile). Schematically, what the build system of A is doing is just

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -DPIC -std=c++17 -fPIC -fopenmp -I<path/to/includes> -Wl,-rpath,<path/to/libs> -L<path/to/libs> -lB A.cc -o libA.so
```

which I assume just builds `libA.so` using the shared library `libB.so`. Ultimately my goal is to link my main program to `libA.so`.

Here is where my problems start. My main program fails to link to `libA.so` claiming some undefined symbols. Looking into `libA.so` with `nm` shows me that it has indeed some undefined symbols, the same ones that were undefined in the static `libB.a`, though this time only one copy of each undefined symbol is shown. Furthermore, when I run `ldd` on `libA.so` it does not show linkage to `libB.so`, which makes me think it's using the static version of the library. However, as a test, I deleted the static libary `libB.a` after building `B` but before building `A`, while leaving the shared library `libB.so` untouched, but that did not change anything.

I also tried to create a static version of `A` and link my main program to that, but it suffers from the same problem where now the undefined symbol linking error turns into an undefined reference to X error.

So my questions are: why doesn't `libB.so` shows when running `ldd` on `libA.so`? Why only the undefined verson of the symbols ends up in `libA.so`, even though I'm (supposedly) linking to `libB.so`, which does not have undefined symbols? What can I do to resolve the issue, knowing that I cannot change the make systems of `A` or `B`, except providing some flags? Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: I just found out that if I create a static version of `A` and link my main program to it *before* linking to `B` it succeeds. I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my questions are: why doesn't libB.so shows when running ldd on libA.so?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849519/50617).

> What can I do to resolve the issue, knowing that I cannot change the make systems of A or B, except providing some flags?

Changing the `libA.so` link command to be `... A.cc -o libA.so -lB` should fix this.